# How to generate UI using Swagger

Tags: angular, swagger, openapi-generator

I'm using SWAGGER to generate android and angular client. Swagger generates services and models only, does swagger generate Angular `.ts` Component as well as `.html forms templates` too? If not, does anyone out here know another generator or tool?

Or do I have to code it by myself?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/verizonconnect/ngx-form-generator can generate Angular ReativeForms from an OpenAPI, re-creating validation logic which is provided in the OpenAPI doc.

It doesnt generate the component .ts or .html.

https://dev.to/martinmcwhorter/generate-angular-reactiveforms-from-swagger-openapi-35h9 provides a walk-though of how to integrate the generated ReativeForms in an app, i.e. example .ts and .html files needed to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

How is it supposed to do that when it doesn't know what exactly do you want to do with that data and with those model services?

It generates a basic CRUD on models inside the services and exposes them as a Module that you can then import in your RootModule or any module that you want to use it in. But you'll have to do the needful of getting the data from these services and presenting it on the DOM.

As far as Generators are concerned, Angular CLI does scaffold out a basic structure of an Angular App for you. But again, it is not going to generate the whole project for you. You'll have to add the relevant Components, and Pipes, and Directives and maybe even Modules.

Comment: Since models and services are known, it would be easy to generate a generic component to be customized

Comment: A generic component that will act similarly for different models? I feel otherwise. I think it would make more harm than good. It's only good when the structure of the models is same.

Answer (score -1):

Swagger and openApi generators allow you to generate proxies to your APIs. They will not generate apps.